# Prevent double quotes in lists of list when reading and writing csv files in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, read-write

Before reading / writing into csv file, when performing the command below on the original pandas dataframe

```
   user
0  [mary, jane]
1  [alex, andrew]
```

When doing the command ->

```
df['user'].to_list()
```

My output looks normal and does not have the weird double-quotes.

```
[['mary', 'jane'], ['alex', 'andrew']]
```

After writing and reading into csv file, my output changed to look like the following with the weird double quotes when performing the same command, how can I maintain the original pandas dataframe without the additional double quotes in my lists when
reading/writing csv files?

```
df = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
df['user'].to_list()
```

Weird Output ->

```
["['mary', 'jane']", "['alex', 'andrew']"]
```

My dataframe also changes to look like this now

```
   user
0  ['mary', 'jane']
1  ['alex', 'andrew']
```

The code that I used to write and read the dataframe is as follow.

```
df.to_csv('users.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
```

I am not sure why is this weird change happening. Any insight is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing into csv, following code can be used in order to remove double quotes. This parameter is an inbuilt feature of df.to_csv()

```
df.to_csv('users.csv',index=False,header= False,sep = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar = ' ')
```

Hope it helps !